# testing web sites on internet explorer with mac

Tags: internet-explorer, testing

I remember one time my friend told me about this great app that lets developers test a web site on multiple IE instances. I am just wondering whether any of you guys know the name of this app.

Comment: I think IE was discontinued on OS X about 8 years ago or so. I don't know if this app you speak of is based on that, or something else entirely.

Comment: It could just be a VM which lets you run windows? Or it could be one of those sites that take screenshots of your site from all different OS's on all different browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [IEs4OSX](http://www.kronenberg.org/ies4osx/), which lets you run mutiple versions of IE in Windows emulation under OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Alkaline lets you test your site with 17 windows browsers from your Mac.
http://litmusapp.com/alkaline/

You can also search Google for Cross Browser Testing for other options.